# What should you store or append a batch of tensors to in C++ when using LibTorch?

Tags: c++, tensor, libtorch

In C++, when using LibTorch (The C++ version of PyTorch), what should you store a batch of tensors in? I'm running into the problem of not being able to reset the batch on the next step because C++ doesn't allow storing a new variable over an existing variable.

In my attempt my batch of tensors is one single 385x385 tensor. The batch size is 385. In a for loop I use `torch::cat` to concatenate 385 smaller 1D tensors, which are 385 numbers long. (Maybe 'stack' or 'append' are better terms for what I'm doing since the are stacked together picket fence style more than 'concatenated', but that's what I'm using.) Anyways, there is not problem with this shape. It seems to work fine for one forward and backward pass but then the tensor becomes 770x385 on the next pass instead of a 385x385 tensor of the next 385, 385 long arrays. I hope I am painting a picture and not being too verbose.

The code.
Near the bottom I have the line `all_step_obs = torch::tensor({});` to try to wipe out the contents of the tensor, AKA, the batch, but this gives me a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I guess for trying to access the tensor outside of the loop(?)
If I don't have this line I get a 770x385 tensor after the next `step`.

The model

```
#include "mujoco/mujoco.h"
struct Net : torch::nn::Module {
    torch::Tensor action_high, action_low;
public:
    Net(torch::Tensor action_high, torch::Tensor action_low)  : action_high(action_high), action_low(action_low){
        // Construct and register two Linear submodules.
        fc1 = torch::nn::Linear(385, 385);
        fc2 = torch::nn::Linear(385, 385);
        fc3 = torch::nn::Linear(385, 42);
        // cholesky_layer = torch::nn::Linear(385, (42 * (42 + 1)) / 2);
        cholesky_layer = torch::nn::Linear(385, 385);
    }

    // Implement the Net's algorithm.
    torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor x) {
        // Use one of many tensor manipulation functions.
        x = torch::relu(fc1->forward(x));
        x = torch::dropout(x, /*p=*/0.2, /*train=*/is_training());
        x = torch::relu(fc2->forward(x));
        auto mean_layer = fc3->forward(x);
        auto mean = action_low + (action_high - action_low) * mean_layer;
        auto chol_l = cholesky_layer->forward(x);
        
        // auto chol = torch::rand({385, 385});

        auto chol = torch::matmul(chol_l, chol_l.transpose(0, 1));

        chol = torch::nan_to_num(chol, 0, 2.0);
        chol = chol.add(torch::eye(385));
        auto cholesky = torch::linalg::cholesky(chol);

        // return torch::cat({mean, cholesky}, 0);
        return mean_layer;
    }

    // Use one of many "standard library" modules.
    torch::nn::Linear fc1{nullptr}, fc2{nullptr}, fc3{nullptr}, cholesky_layer{nullptr};
};
```

The training

```
auto high = torch::ones({385, 42}) * 0.4;
auto low = torch::ones({385, 42}) * -0.4;
auto actor = Net(low, high);

int max_steps = 385;
int steps = 2000;
auto l1_loss = torch::smooth_l1_loss;
auto optimizer = torch::optim::Adam(actor.parameters(),  3e-4);

torch::Tensor train() {
    torch::Tensor all_step_obs;

    for (int i = 0; i<steps; ++i)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<max_steps; ++i)
        {
            all_step_obs = torch::cat({torch::rand({385}).unsqueeze(0), all_step_obs});
        }
        auto mean = actor.forward(all_step_obs);

        auto loss = l1_loss(mean, torch::rand({385, 42}), 1, 0);

        optimizer.zero_grad();
        loss.backward();
        optimizer.step();

        all_step_obs = torch::tensor({});

        if (steps == 1999) {
            return loss;
        }
    }
};

int main (int argc, const char** argv) {

    std::cout << train();
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the segmentation fault, can you double check that this snippet does fail for you ? Also, can you narrow it down to find the line that produces the segfault and can you explicit the expected size of the output of actor.forward ?

Comment: "explicit the expected size of the output of actor.forward?" It's actually 385x385. I was confusing it with the output, but that wasn't the issue anyways... I've cleaned up the OP a bit to hopefully include the model and make the data input to `forward` just a random 385x385 tensor. It throws the same error it does with my data. I've looked at other LibTorch programs and they use a data loader, but I am doing Q Learning, so I need to input specific numbers as they are observed / created. I don't have a dataset to sample. Let me know if this is now reproducible now.

Comment: After thinking about it, maybe the loop that creates the batch should be its own function outside of this function? I don't know if this would create a new problem for what I need in the end. I don't have time to write it today.

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce the segfault, can you confirm that you are not getting another kind of error like some weird c10 error ? What kind of libtorch version are you using ? I'm stuck with 1.8 :( 
Yes you could clean/improve this code (I think datasets and dataloaders could even be used here) but let's address the segfault first. 
Can you make this code more minimal ? Remove everything you can until you have a code with only a couple lines which yields the segfault

Comment: I set most of the variables `torch::Tensor train() {
    torch::Tensor all_step_obs;
    torch::Tensor loss;
    torch::Tensor mean;` at the top of the function instead of using `auto` and I'm not getting the segfault anymore.